# Setting Docker's deploy.resources.limits.cpus with an unknown number of cores?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

It's plausible that machines in a cluster have different numbers of cores. Docker Swarm mode's `deploy.resources.limits.cpus` config specifies the absolute number of cores. Is it possible to specify a percentage of the total available CPU resources? I want the total CPU limit to be close to 100% of the max capacity.

dockerfile snippet:

```
deploy:
  resources:
    limits:
      cpus: '1'
      memory: 4G
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no.

If you have a service that actually can benefit from multiple cores, set the cpu limit to the a reasonable common divisor of the min and max cores your nodes have available, and then just set the replicas to a number such that deploy.replicas * deploy.resource.limits.cpus ~= total-swarm-cpus.